# Is there limitations in using blogger feed json_in_script

Tags: blogger

I have a blogger website(blogspot) and it is now getting more traffic daily which prompted me to create an android app for my readers. I'm using my `blogger` feed url `<script src="http://mysite.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/summary/-/Blogger?max-results=5&alt=json-in-script&callback=mycallback"></script>`

Am worried if their is limitation by blogger using my method (feed json_in_script) to access my site in my app like bandwidth, number of calls to the feed url e.t.c.

Pls: my website is just text and images and also not adult site.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not limit, feel free to use it as much as u want

Comment: While I tend to believe this, it'd be a lot better with some sort of evidence/citation.

Comment: @ceejayoz i'm just curious to know because google cancelled my developer account for no specific reason. So i don't want to experience another hit after much work. And i read it online that one shouldn't labour on blogspot that they might destroy it anytime. I'm just hoping there isn't any limitation